# Convert csv files to parquet on s3 using Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to create a Spark application that will read my csv files from s3, convert it to parquet files and write the results to s3.

I have 8 new csv files every minute compressed with gzip (~60MB each gzip file), each row have ~200 columns and ~99% are at the same date (my partition column).

The cluster have 3 workers with 10 cores and memory of 20 GB each.

Here is my code:

```
val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Csv2Parquet")
    .config("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem")
    .config("fs.s3a.access.key", "MY ACESS KEY")
    .config("fs.s3a.secret.key", "MY SECRET")
    .config("spark.executor.memory", "15G")
    .config("spark.driver.memory", "5G")
    .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._

val schema= StructType(Array(
    StructField("myDate", DateType, nullable=false),
    StructField("myTimestamp", TimestampType, nullable=true),
    ...
    ...
    ...
    StructField("myColumn200", StringType, nullable=true)
    ))

val df = spark.readStream
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .schema(schema)
    .option("header", "false")
    .option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED")
    .option("delimiter","\t")
    .load("s3a://my-bucket/raw-data/*.gz")
    .withColumn("myPartitionDate", $"myDate")

val query = df.repartition($"myPartitionDate").writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/shared/checkpoints/csv2parquet")
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(60000))
    .format("parquet")
    .option("path", "s3a://my-bucket/parquet-data")
    .partitionBy(myPartitionDate)
    .start("s3a://my-bucket/parquet-data")

query.awaitTermination()
```

The problem is that only one task is responsible for writing the "main" partition (that includes 99% of the events) to s3 and it takes ~4 minutes to handle this task. how can i improve it?

[image: first stage]

[image: second stage]

Comment: The answer is simple - don't use `gzip` compression. It is not splittable, so processing each file with a single task is the best Spark can do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will give it a try but i don't think its the issue cause at the start of the batch i have 8 tasks (8 gzip files), right after i see that spark shuffle the data (because of the repartition) and i have 200 tasks but only one of them takes ~4 minutes

Comment: @RazOmessi have you been able to resolve this issue.   I am having the same issue where I am trying to process data in S3 using structured streaming but only one task is processing...  Not sure how to scale it.

Comment: assuming that you are using EMR to run a job you can use s3-dist-cp to copy to hdfs and unzip on the fly in a distributed way. after that, you can read data from these files and process them further.